# React + internal Flask API: what are the best options for deployment?

Tags: reactjs, flask, deployment

Currently during development I'm running `yarn start` for my React frontend and then `flask run` for the Flask API.

My directory tree currently looks like the following:

```
_ application_name
  |_ api (Flask)
     |_ app.py
     |_ venv
  |_ node_modules
  |_ public
  |_ src
```

Also if it helps I'm using React's routing library, so all routes are taken care of on the frontend. The backend exists as more of a service - I thought maybe Heroku makes sense for the Flask side? But I'm not sure about the front end. Or should everything be packaged and deployed as one? As you might be able to tell, I'm quite a novice when it comes to development and deployment.

Comment: How about dockerizing your app and then you can deploy it pretty much anywhere ?

Comment: @thug_ I'll look into that, thanks. From my understanding dockerizing provides a virtual env for the application, so it can be used just as if it's running on my own local machine?

Comment: Dockerizing means basically writing Dockerfiles and building docker images for your front-end react service and your Python backend service. Locally you can run them together using `docker-compose` for example. After that you can deploy it anywhere, most of the cloud platforms support deploying it with Docker. Heroku example https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker